# Working with text file in python - copy vertical text and paste it horizontally

Tags: python, csv, text

How to copy vertical text and paste it horizontally as csv.

```
input_text_file = """
Statement 1
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
Statement 2
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
Statement 3
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
Statement 4
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
...........
"""
```

Check if the line starts with *Statement*, copy everything till the next line that starts with *Statement* and paste it horizontally as csv (comma separated).

Not all the Statements have the same number of lines.

```
with open('input_text_file', 'r') as intext:
    for line in intext:
        if line.startwith('Statement'):
            continue till the next line.startwith('Statement')
            ..........


with open('output_csv_file', 'w') as csvfile:
    write to csv file


output_csv_file ="""
Statement 1,Statement 2,Statement 3,Statement 4
some text  ,some text  ,some text  ,some text  
some text  ,some text  ,some text  ,some text  
some text  ,some text  ,some text  ,some text  
some text  ,some text  ,some text  ,some text  
some text  ,some text  ,some text  ,some text  
some text  ,some text  ,some text  ,some text  
some text              ,some text  ,some text
                       ,some text  ,some text
                       ,some text
                       ,some text
                       ,some text
"""
```

How to achieve this in python?

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: Well you are almost there: gather everything after the line containing `Statement` into a list, and store that list in a dictionary indexed by the statement line. When you have read everything, zip the lists to get the rows to write to the csv file (after the header row...). Give it a try, and feel free to ask a new question if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: Serge Ballesta - Would you help with the code please!

Comment: Michael Butscher - The problem is that I'm getting stack with the code, not sure how to write it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following iterative approach with [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
import csv

with StringIO(input_text_file) as f, open('result.csv', 'w') as out:
    d = {}

    for row in f:
        row = row.strip()
        if row:
            if row.startswith('Statement'):  # capture key/column name
                key = row
                d[key] = []
            else:
                d[key].append(row)
                
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(d.keys())  # write header
    writer.writerows(zip(*d.values()))
```

---

`result.csv` contents:

```
Statement 1,Statement 2,Statement 3,Statement 4
some text,some text,some text,some text
some text,some text,some text,some text
some text,some text,some text,some text
some text,some text,some text,some text
some text,some text,some text,some text
some text,some text,some text,some text
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!

For some reason, I get an extra empty line in between rows, and if one or more Statements have more lines of text those lines do not get in the CSV file.

Comment: @new_py, I've used the input sample from your question literally, it shows that each `Statement` have equal number of values

Comment: you are right, but how can I handle that? I'll update the question!

Comment: @new_py: the extra empty line is caused by the csv module explicitely handling the eol. Because of that the output files are expected to be opened as `open(..., newline='')` to prevent the io system to add a extra newline.

Comment: @new_py: to allow some `Statement` to have more lines than others, you just have to use `zip_longest` from the `itertools` module instead of `zip`.

Comment: @ZachYoung, check question's history. The correct solution was built on the initial sample. You can change your input many times - that does not mean an answerer must indulge that whims

Comment: @ZachYoung I added the newline='' and zip_longest!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, ah sorry, I misunderstood.